What is the best way to combine ExternalEvaluate with RemoteRunProcess?
session = StartExternalSession["Python"] starts a python session on the local machine.
remote = RemoteConnect["host.example.com"] opens a connection over the network to run shell commands on the remote host.
Is there a way to open an 'external evaluation session' (Python, R, Julia, Octave, ...) on a remote host?
